# Problems previewing documents in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, wpf, print-preview

I'm trying to create a WPF which can preview documents(word,pdf,png,jpg) located on my HDD. I've tried using printPreviewControl but I cant get it working.

Code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    initComponents();
}

public void initComponents()
    { 
        try
        {
            string fname = "C:\\Users\\Gebruiker\\Desktop\\PDF en DOC\\test.pdf";
            streamToPrint = new StreamReader(fname, Encoding.UTF8);
            try
            {
                PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
                pd = new PrintDocument();
                pd.DocumentName = fname;

                //Get responsive width and height.
                System.Drawing.Rectangle workingRectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
                int height = workingRectangle.Height / 100 * 85;
                int width = workingRectangle.Width / 100 * 75;

                //Settings printPreviewControl
                printPreviewControl1.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(width, height);
                printPreviewControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
                printPreviewControl1.Document = pd;
            }
            finally
            {
                streamToPrint.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
 }
```

*It says its generating the preview, but stays empty, watch image below:

[image: Generating preview..]

If you guys have any other solution, I'm open to try.

Thanks

Comment: *"preview documents"* - that's broad. Choose one document type, [research](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37787/Document-Preview-Application) (google), repeat for all. Then you will know. Btw, who told you `printPreviewControl` *can* do that? Was it the name of [`PrintPreviewControl.Document`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printpreviewcontrol.document(v=vs.110).aspx) property? ;)

Comment: I've searched for multiple solutions but I cant get it working. Main documents i want to preview are Word and PDF's. I've chosen for PrintViewControl because I think it can basicly handle any file type.

Comment: `printPreviewControl1.Document = pd;` IMO you should not set the Document before all data are prepared. Instead set it right when the preview is requested. The preview is generated right when and only(!) when the Document is set..